Why is "mit" (meaning among) considered adverb?
On english wiktionary I ran across "mit" labeled as adverb. Example

Hier gibt es mit das beste Essen in der Stadt. (Here they have some of the best food in town.)

Noting that the preposition "mit" takes the dative, so the distinction between preposition and adverb would make a difference here.
Spontaneuosly I would consider it a preposition in this situation. Also if you then lookup "among" in wiktionary it is listed as a preposition only (and one of the examples is quite similar: "He is among the few who completely understand the subject.")
So basically why is "mit" here an adverb and not preposition?

It might help to look at some German language dictionaries here as well; German Wiktionary and DWDS both have similar meanings of "mit" as an adverb.

English and German appear to be similar when looking at examples like the following.

Sie ist mit die bekannteste Künstlerin der letzten Jahre.
She is among the most famous artists in recent years.

However, this is deceiving. Distributionally, the phrases marked in bold behave differently. English phrases headed by among behave like prepositional phrases: they can't function as subjects (1) or complements (2) to most prepositions, but can function as adjuncts of place (3). The reverse is true for the German phrases, which behave like noun phrases.


Mit die bekannteste Künstlerin der letzten Jahre kommt morgen nach Hamburg.
*Among the most famous artists in recent years comes to Hamburg tomorrow.

Als nächstes sprechen wir über mit die bekannteste Künstlerin der letzten Jahre.
*Next, we speak about among the most famous artists in recent years.

*Ich saß mit die beste Künstlerin.
I sat among the best artists.



This leads to classify mit as some kind of modifier of the noun phrase it precedes, no different from ausgerechnet, nur, gerade, sogar, schon. These words stand alone; they have no complements and do not govern case, hence traditional grammar calls them adverbs.
Going back to the original pair of examples, it is not only the syntax, but also the semantics that are different.

Sie ist mit die bekannteste Künstlerin der letzten Jahre.
She is among the most famous artists in recent years.

Adverbial mit occurs with noun phrases in the singular; the preposition among requires a noun phrase in the plural. The noun phrase mit die bekannteste Künstlerin designates a person: one of the most famous artists. The prepositional phrase among the most famous artists (German unter den berühmtesten Künstlerinnen) is an adverbial (relating a person as belonging to a group) that can occur for instance with verbs like be or sit or a pronoun like one.

I've learnt that adverbs are modifying words other than nouns (or even the entire clause), but the term maybe have slightly different meaning depending on the language (described). As for the third example (I assume asterisk means incorrect sentence): it would for example be "...saß mit der...", right? Or if we're talking about what this question is about "...saß mit mit die..." , or? I also now noted that it's singular in German (which is interesting to IMHO)
